# Is it classed as sexual activity?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom

In relation to the definition of ‘sexual activity’ I am wondering if explicit/nude photos would be classed as "sexual activity" under [S4 SOA 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/4)?

Comment: Are you wanting to see whether explicit/nude photos are classified as "sexual activity" or whether the S4 offence applies in a given situation?

Comment: @matthew both really....

Comment: So say under S4 - it can be prosecuted under deceit, if someone send nude photos to someone who is ultimately catfishing them, would this class as this offence?

Answer (score 1):

## Do nudes count as "sexual activity"?

Yes, look at [Section 78](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/78) of the Act (emphasis mine):

> For the purposes of this Part (except sections 15A and 71), penetration, touching or **any other activity** is sexual if a reasonable person would consider that—
>
> (a) whatever its circumstances or any person’s purpose in relation to it, it is because of its nature sexual, or
>
> (b) because of its nature it may be sexual and because of its circumstances or the purpose of any person in relation to it (or both) it is sexual.

Nudes would probably be considered sexual by the reasonable person under subsection A and so the taking of nude/explicit photos would be considered a "sexual activity" under Section 4.

## Has an offence under S4 been committed if A is a catfisher?

Only if the person sending nudes (B) doesn't consent to doing so. Deceit in such a fashion would seemingly vitiate consent (since B is unable to make an informed choice) and therefore potentially render it null and void under [Section 75](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/76) of the Act. Most likely under subsection (a) unless B knows the person "personally".

> (1) If in proceedings for an offence to which this section applies it is proved that the defendant did the relevant act and that any of the circumstances specified in subsection (2) existed, it is to be conclusively presumed—
>
> (a) that the complainant did not consent to the relevant act, and
>
> (b) that the defendant did not believe that the complainant consented to the relevant act.
>
> (2) The circumstances are that—
>
> (a) the defendant intentionally deceived the complainant as to the nature or purpose of the relevant act;
>
> (b) the defendant intentionally induced the complainant to consent to the relevant act by impersonating a person known personally to the complainant.

This means that S4(1)(c) would apply and it would appear that the offence is made out:

> (1) A person (A) commits an offence if—
>
> (a) he intentionally causes another person (B) to engage in an activity,
>
> (b) the activity is sexual,
>
> (c) B does not consent to engaging in the activity, and
>
> (d) A does not reasonably believe that B consents.

Ultimately, whether such deceit gives rise to a criminal conviction would be for a jury to determine.

Comment: Okay, but if the person had already taken the photos (not because they were asked for) but sent them, would that still be classed under S4? As the photos were taken off their own accord? But sent to the catfish?

Comment: What if the ‘catfish’ didn’t ask for them and they were sent on their own accord?

Comment: 1) The activity could still potentially be regarded as sexual as it's possible the intent is to cause sexual arousal. 

2) No, an S4 offence wouldn't have been committed if they were sent freely of B's own accord and the catfish didn't ask for them, etc.

Comment: thank you. One other thing, what if the catfish sent an explicit photo to them, and they sent a photo back, again without the catfish specifically asking for one?

Comment: Same thing. No S4 offence, but possibly other offences depending on B's age.

Comment: Reading the same language, I would not find it at all a clear that merely taking a nude photo constitutes "sexual activity" (unless it also depicted some sort of further sexual activity which the individual was induced to engage in such as using a sex toy or masturbating). There is probably case law on point. It would also be a rare case in which sending a nude of oneself would be consider not done with consent although I could imagine some extraordinary and convoluted situations (e.g. kidnapping style duress) where it might.

Comment: @matthew hypothetically, everyone would be over 18